# Overcoming the binary incompetence in regards to fractions

Tags: python, module, binary, addition

I am trying to add fractions together (1/5 and such), and since binary is unable to add certain fractions, I'm getting really horrible answers like 2.99999999999996 and so on. I understand I can use math.round (since pythons round is not actually round) to get it to 3, but I don't want that.

Is there any module I can use to add two numbers together (such as 0.2 and 0.2) and get a result of something other then 0.39999999999999999999999996?

EDIT:

I tried using decimal, the result I got from this after inputting 6, 12, 24 and 24 is 2.9999999999:

```
while True:
            try:
                x += 1
                print("\n" + "Enter resistance of resistor " + str(x))
                resistors.append(int(input()))
            except:
                temp = Decimal(0)
                print(temp)
                for i in resistors:
                    print(temp)
                    temp += Decimal(1)/Decimal(i) 
                temp = temp**-1
                print("\n" + "The total resistance of inputted resistors in parallel is: " + str(temp))
                input()
                break
```

Comment: Use a decimal type instead: https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html

Comment: Or the built-in fraction type: https://docs.python.org/2/library/fractions.html

Comment: There is also a [fractions](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/fractions.html) module in the standard library.

Comment: In 3.6  from anaconda I have `'%.24f'%0.4` → `0.400000000000000022204460`,  `'%.24f'%(0.2+0.2)` → `0.400000000000000022204460` — How did you find that `0.39999999999999999999999996` you quoted? Just curious, do you have quad precision enabled by default?

Comment: `1/sum(1/x for x in (6, 12, 24, 24))` → `2.9999999999999996`, 
the error is `(3-1/sum(1/x for x in (6, 12, 24, 24)))/3` → `1.4802973661668753e-16` — Let's multiply this error by the distance Sun Earth expressed in mm, `150*1E6*1E6*(3-1/sum(1/x for x in (6, 12, 24, 24)))/3` → `0.02220446049250313`. Final question, `6` is a _nominal_ resistance, isn't it? If you are _really_ concerned by these matters you could have a look at _interval arithmetic_ (there are also Python modules that deal with it).

Comment: Thanks for this, I think I will just leave it or round it to 5 decimal places.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not "binary incompetence". It is a result of using real machines to represent idealized mathematical entities. There are an infinite number of real numbers between 0 and 1. Whatever representation you use, binary, ternary, octal, decimal or hex, if you have only a finite number of digits, then some of those real numbers are going to have to share the same representation. You can't represent 1/100 accurately in binary because it is a recurring binary fraction. Just as you can't represent 1/3 in decimal because it is a recurring decimal fraction. But when your 4-function pocket calculator shows 1/3 as 0.3333333 you don't call that decimal incompetence.

If you want to represent rational numbers accurately then you can use the `fractions` module:

```
>>> import fractions
>>> fifth = fractions.Fraction(1,5)
>>> fifth * 2
Fraction(2, 5)
```

But when you convert `Fraction(2,5)` to a float, you go back to floating point representation.

I think that not is the real issue, though. I think you just need to fix this line:

```
print("\n" + "The total resistance of inputted resistors in parallel is: " + str(temp))
```

That is giving you the default string representation of the number, which shows the closest possible representation to the highest possible precision. But you actually want to see a *nice number*:

```
print("\n" + "The total resistance of inputted resistors in parallel is: %g" % temp)
```

Comment: Wow, well that solved it. I never thought to use that.... And it works, perfectly. I understand "binary incompetence" is highly offensive to binary and I should include decimals when insulting mathematical inaccuracies as well!